# Find name of stored procedure in mysql based where a particular keyword is used

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How to find the name of all stored procedure where a particular keyword is used. E.g. I wan to get the name of all stored procedures in database where "User_master" table is used.

If I will do it manually it will take a long time is there any query or function through which i can easily get the same.

Comment: This [LINK](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-find-a-stored-procedure-containing-text.html) might help

Answer (score 0):

The below query worked :

> SELECT routine_name,created,last_altered FROM
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
>
> WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'databasename'
>
> AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
>
> And ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%keyword%'